# Learning Sql Symbols used by Teachers

Tags: sql

What is this constraint symbol in SQL?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That symbol is the [subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) symbol.

It means that all the values of the `B` attribute of the `s` entity are in the set of values 
found in the `A` attribute of the `r` entity.

When expressed as SQL:

```
alter table s add foreign key (B) references r(A); -- mysql
```

The exact syntax may vary slightly with whatever database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol refers to **SUBSET**·

The set on left has its values contained in set on right of symbol.
It is analogous to `<=` comparison operator.
[**WIKIPEDIA**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset)